# Is the $ sign not recognized by Rhino Script Engine?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm trying to call a javascript from my java class. Please find below my java code:

```
    File file = new File(".....js");
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
 // create a JavaScript engine
                                    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByExtension("js");
                                    engine.put("engine", engine);
                                    // evaluate JavaScript code from String
                                    try{
                                        engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader(file));
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    } catch (ScriptException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

My javascript contains a dollar sign '$' ... So, I'm getting this error once I run my program:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#4) in <Unknown source> at line number 4
```

Is '$' not defined as part of the javascript code? Does the Script engine don't recognize it? Thanks for any help.

This is my updated script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">

$.ajax({
                              type: 'POST',
                              url: "../ManageChannel",
                              data: "_country="+country+"&_featured="+featured+"&_webviewLink="+webviewLink+"&_name="+locationName,
                             success:function(data)
                             {
                                 if (data==2)

                                alert("RSS link is required");

                            else{
                                alert("Channel is successfully created!");
                                filePath=[];
                                window.location.href=window.location.href;


                            }

                                }});
```

Comment: How do you define `$` ? This character is usable in JavaScript variable names but if you don't define the variable (for example using a library), it's undefined.

Comment: @dystroy $(document).ready(function () {.....}

Comment: Well... Do you import jQuery ?

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, jQuery is *not* part of the ECMAScript spec. Neither is the DOM or XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @ Joachim @ Stephen I loaded the jquery library and it's still not running...refer please to the script i attached above

Comment: @user2505456: why do you think that Rhino would parse and/or react to HTML? Those `<script>` tags are not JavaScript. Rhino does JavaScript! This might be relevant for you: http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/

Comment: i encountered this issue and i realized ajax is calling an http url which i can call from java code. this means i don't need to use scriptengine when calling an ajax. I just need to use the url in my java code. or if it is within your application, then just call it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example javascript looks like jquery code.  Maybe you just need to import the jquery library ...

For how to deal with `XMLHttpRequest` in Rhino, see this Q&A: [XMLHttpRequest in Rhino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985560/xmlhttprequest-in-rhino).

As Joachim points out, `jquery`, the `DOM` APIs and `XMLHttpRequest` are not part of the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: My script contain a xmlhttprequest together with an ajax call and some parsing to the parameters

Comment: even the **xmlhttprequest** is not being recognized by the script engine

Comment: @user2505456 - See Joachim's comment.