# How to send an HTTP request using Javascript within a BPMN model's script task?

Tags: javascript, camunda

I wold like to send an HTTP request from within a script task in a BPMN model executed by Camunda using Javascript. Does anyone know how to do that?

I've already tested this:

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://test.local/append.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But once I get to the script task containing the above code, `Tasklist` prompts that `XMLHttpRequest` is not found.

Comment: Is your Javascript code server-side? If so, `XMLHttpRequest` is unavailable in your case; it only exists in browsers

Comment: The javascript code above is executed by Java run time. To be honest it's my first time experiencing it myself. It surely is not executed in a browser environment but I'm not sure if it is the same as running it as a server-side code! How can I make an Ajax call in a server-side javascript? I can test it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Java version you either use the Rhino (until Java 7) or Nashorn (since Java 8) Javascript engine. Both have no concept of XmlHttpRequest as you know it from Javascript engines in web browsers. So you have to use a library which allows you to send HTTP Requests. This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985560/xmlhttprequest-in-rhino) links a XmlHttpRequest implementation for Rhino.

Answer (score 0):

The Nashorn JavaScript engine used by Camunda may not support `XmlHttpRequest` itself, but it *does* support Java "interop," so you can just instantiate and use Java classes from within JavaScript, and send HTTP requests the way you would do it in Java. This is especially useful, if you just want to use the default Camunda docker image for example without having to customize or install anything on the server side:

```js
// HttpClient version (Java 11+)
// get Java types
var HttpClient = Java.type("java.net.http.HttpClient");
var HttpRequest = Java.type("java.net.http.HttpRequest");
var HttpResponse = Java.type("java.net.http.HttpResponse");
var URI = Java.type("java.net.URI");
// create JSON object
var data = {
    activityInstanceId: execution.getActivityInstanceId(),
    currentActivityInstanceId: execution.getCurrentActivityId()
};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
// create request
var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create("http://10.0.0.5:9090/notify"))
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonData))
    .build();
// fire and forget
client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

See the [Java 11 `HttpClient` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) and the [Nashorn Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html) for more information. Similarly, you can use [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) on older platforms, or even just open a TCP socket.